# git-commit-id-plugin Git Repository Location

Tags: git, maven

In project I use git-commit-id-plugin.
Configuration:

```xml
 <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <prefix>git</prefix>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties
                    </generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                    <gitDescribe>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <always>false</always>
                        <dirty>-dirty</dirty>
                    </gitDescribe>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

When mvn pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.6:revision:

```
[INFO] --- git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.6:revision (get-the-git-infos) 
Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: myProject/documentation/������.odt.
```

Why does  look not only at folder ".git", but and "myProject/documentation"?

File name - "Дискуссия_ТЗ_2.
I changed name of file (Discussion_TZ_2) - and everything worked.